# How to archive database to new database ? MSSQL Archive

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that will grow and become slower. My initiate plan was to let it grow and use it. But my queries take a lot of time. Then I read about archiving. It seems to fit in perfectly but I can not seem to get how to implement it.

I would like to archive it on a monthly basis, I have planed to use the SQL server agent and making a job that runs once each month. For the moment I would like to keep the data for ever, but if I would like to keep it for lets say 5 years, can I then use jobs for deleting those databases that are above 5 years as well ?

The tags that are large will have a timestamp when they are created, I would like to move the entire database to a new database called databasename.archive.2020June.

**How can I do this as basic and safe as possible?** Before starting this kind of job, I guess I will first do a backup of the database but.The reason I would like to archive and not backup is that I might need to read values from them.  I need some guidance on how to achieve this. I could not find a guide that shows how it can be done.

The software used will be Microsoft SQL Server developer 2019. I know that this will not become smaller, but if someone wants the data from march 3 years ago. My guess is that the query should be fast if they are archived.

Best regards, 
muli.

Comment: "I have a database that will grow and become slower." - that inidicates bad programming and missing indices. WHile db's GET slower, it should happen VERY slowly and unless you hit terabytes of data - it should be something you can work around. Yiou are much better served sitting down and fixing the problems. You create a nightmare, especially for multi database queries (which are not natively supported, so you end up with eithera db view setup or rewritign all relevant queries).

Comment: better .. a proper query tuning with  the necessary indexes

Comment: The problem is that it will become on terabyte size, so that is why I can not seem to find a solution for this problem. My data per year will be about 150 gb, a querry on 200 gb took about 30 seconds. Might be bad programming since im a beginner. Or is this just the way it is?

Comment: Say I would like to calculate a average of a column. Should'nt this take ages if I Would have 200 gb of data and use datetime ? :)

Comment: A terabyte DB is not particularly big these days. If the data needs to remain available for querying, look into partitioning the table and storing the old partitions on separate filegroups. With partitioned data, it becomes much easier to delete old data if you're no longer interested in it (`TRUNCATE TABLE ... WITH (PARTITIONS ...)`). For actually speeding up queries over huge data sets, things like columnstore indexes and Analysis Services cubes become interesting.

Comment: I've read that it is not big actually. But why do they say that partioning is dangerous? Could not get that.

It is speeding up the data I want to extract im trying to find a solution.

Lets say if we partion the data in different months. Can I then seek for different partions? Say the first partion is this months, can I make querry to look for 5 partions down (5 months ago) ? :)

Comment: I don't know who "they" are, but partitioning is not dangerous. Implementing partitioning has a learning curve because there's a few concepts and moving objects to tackle (partition functions, schemes, file groups, boundaries), but there's no danger. Of course, before making any big structural change to a DB a backup is advisable.

Comment: I only have testing data at the moment and eager to learn. But being new to DB and mssql is not that fun sometimes. Let's say we have 1 tb data. What would an average of say 100gb take to calculatE? Are we taking 2 seconds, or 20 ? :)

Comment: This depends on the size of your rows, the speed of your I/O subsystem, CPU speed, the amount of memory available, memory bandwidth, the presence of indexes and whether or not the query is written to do a proper range search. Nobody can give you a hard number on that; you'll just have to optimize until it's fast enough. Performing aggregate queries over large datasets (like an average over a single column) can be done very efficiently with a columnstore index.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, why is it such a bad idea to archive ? In this case I dont really mean the same type of archive as previous since query accros databases dont have native support. But Is  a historical database worth making? Will look up columnstore index and what it is :) Never heard of it. Thanks !

Comment: Archiving is not a bad idea if you don't need to access the data anymore, or access will be a rare and infrequent event. Otherwise, archiving is an inferior solution to partitioning because it complicates the way the data needs to be accessed for no good reason. Partitioning effectively splits a logical table into multiple physical tables but making them appear as one table, meaning that query performance can improve without having to shuffle around data manually. And of course you can partition *and* archive data (possibly in a new DB with a new structure), whatever is most appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing when I should partitioning? :) And if I choose to partition, do I make that once in the tables or do I need to partition when making selects ? :)

Comment: I have some thoughts I cant really find.

Dates were really slow to read on. Is it possible to partitionize them on a rolling matter? A dynamic partitionize ? 

And when should I partitionize them, it should be before inserting the values. I tried on a database yesterday that had 670 millions values and the result was a crash. I Used the script on SSMS. Is it through a function I partitionize them? :) 

Thanks for all the great answers !